# How do I update the java source and target options from 6 to 7?

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to run a .bat file that will decompile code so i can work on it in eclipse. however, when i run the file it says, "error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later. error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later." i have searched the entire web and have no idea how to change my target option  and source option. I am using java 18, im double clicking the batch file and when i type java -version and javac -verison it returns 18.0.1 if that helps.

EDIT:

i found a command to do this, javac -source 18 -target 18 -bootclasspath C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1\lib. the command wont work in program files tho, because of the space. any help here?

Comment: To address your edit, wrap the path in quotes. `javac -source 18 -target 18 -bootclasspath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1\lib"`

Answer (score 0):

Well if you trying to decompile code of .jar file you can try to use "Java Decompiler" from [here](http://java-decompiler.github.io). Hope this maybe helps.

Comment: its not decompiling .jar files, im asking how to change my source and target